# Installing Express Js api with apache and ssl

Tags: express, apache, ssl, lets-encrypt

I need help to install my express js api on apache2 with ssl enabled but I didn't succed

The apache server is on the same that the express js api

My express js app

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('node:path');
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require('https')

const paths = path.join(__dirname, 'paths');
const pathsFiles = fs.readdirSync(paths).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./privatekey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./certificate.pem'),
};

for (const file of pathsFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(paths, file);
    const p = require(filePath);
    app.get(p.path, (req,res)=> p.execute(req,res))    
}


app.get("/image",(req,res)=> res.sendStatus(403))

const server = https.createServer(options,app).listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Serveur à l'écoute")
})
```

My apache config

iglee.fr.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName iglee.fr
    ServerAlias www.iglee.fr
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/idea_website"
    <Directory "/var/www/idea_website">
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.website.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.website.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =iglee.fr [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.iglee.fr
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

iglee.fr-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName iglee.fr
    ServerAlias www.iglee.fr
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/idea_website"
    <Directory "/var/www/idea_website">
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.website.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.website.log combined
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/iglee.fr/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/iglee.fr/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Can you help me please ?
I'm really lost